# Let F be the additive group of all functions mapping R into R. Let K be the subgroup of continuous functions in F.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be the additive group of all functions mapping $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$. Let $K$ be the subgroup of continuous functions in $F$. Can you find an element of $F/K$ having order $2$? Why or why not?

It's not possible because if theres an f of order 2 then it can't be continuous.  it would be $f+f = g$ where $g \in K$. i.e. $g$ would be continuous. But if f has order 2 then its not in $K$ and if its not already in there its not going to become continuous by $f+f$

Comment: oh I was reading a different problem of similar type I will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g=f+f=2f$ is continuous, then how can we recover $f$ from $g$ to show that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: If $g=2f \implies f= \frac{g}{2}$. We would have  $f+K$ as an element with order 2 but then $f \not\in K$, why is this?

Comment: The assumption is that $f \notin K$ but $g \in K$. Is this possible, given that $f = \frac{g}{2}$?

Comment: no, then f would be in K because f would be continuous as well but f is not in K, f is in F/K, namely f+K

Comment: Why the delete vote? @oliverjones You have everything you need. Just put it together. Remember the question was whether or not such an $f$ can exist. Can it?

Comment: I didn't delete a vote. No it can't exist cause the contradiction of being inside and outside of K simultaneously.

Comment: That's the answer! There is no element of order $2$ in $F/K$.